# Idiomatic table cell renderers in Scala

Tags: swing, scala, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I had been using the traditional Java `TableCellRenderer` approach for providing the renderers in a `scala.swing.Table` where I declare my renderers on the table's `TableColumnModel`. The code for this looked like:

```
val myTable = new Table {
  lazy val tcm = initColumnModel
  peer.setColumnModel(tcm)

  override 
  protected def rendererComponent(sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, row: Int, col: Int) = {
    //GET THE VALUE FROM THE TableModel
    val value = model.getValueAt(
                        peer.convertRowIndexToModel(row), 
                        peer.convertColumnIndexToModel(col))
    //GET THE RENDERER FROM THE ColumnModel
    val renderer = tcm.getColumn(col).getCellRenderer
    //WRAP IN A COMPONENT
    Component.wrap(renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        peer, 
                        value, 
                        sel, 
                        foc, 
                        row, 
                        col).asInstanceOf[JComponent])
   }
}
```

Unfortunately this appears to have a memory leak - presumably because I am creating a new Component instance for every cell in the table (for ~30k rows). Certainly when I replace my scala table with a `JTable` (using exactly the same *column* and *data* models) my memory leak goes away.

My question is therefore, what sort of code do people use when overriding the `rendererComponent` method assuming one has ones own cell renderers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiomatic way of using Scala table cell renderers is to use `Table.AbstractRenderer` (if implementing your own) or one of its subclasses:

```
val tcr = new Table.AbstractRenderer[MyObj, MyRenderer](new MyRenderer) {
  def configure(t: Table, sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, o: MyObj, row: Int, col: Int) = {
    //component variable is bound to your renderer
    component.prepare(o)
  }
}
```

In this case `prepare` is a method you would define on your own renderer class:

```
class MyRenderer extends Label {
  def prepare(o: MyObj) {
      text = o.toString //or whatever
  }
}
```

Then this is used by overriding the `rendererComponent` method on `Table`:

```
val t = new Table {
  override def rendererComponent(sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, row: Int, col: Int) = {
     //FIND VALUE
     val v = model.getValueAt(
                       peer.convertRowIndexToModel(row), 
                       peer.convertColumnIndexToModel(row))
     col match {
       case 0 => tcr.componentFor(this, sel, foc, v, row, col)
     }
  }
}
```

Scala comes with its own implementations of `AbstractRenderer`, namely `LabelRenderer` which takes a function as an argument, converting an instance of **MyObj** to a `Tuple2` consisting of a `String` and an `Icon`, for that label to display:

```
val ltcr = new LabelRenderer[MyObj] ( (o: MyObj) => (null, o.toString)  )
```

Comment: I think you want `peer.convertColumnIndexToModel(col)` instead of `peer.convertColumnIndexToModel(row)`

Comment: You can also use `scala.swing.Table.viewToModelColumn(Int): Int`. Note sure why there isn't an equivalent wrapper method for rows..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a ton for your example oxbow_lakes!

IMHO this scala-thing has become as ugly as table-rendering can possibly get.
Trying to hide it as much as possible...

```
class TableRenderer[A](comp: TableRendererComp[A]) extends Table.AbstractRenderer[A,TableRendererComp[A]](comp) {
  def configure(t: Table, sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, a: A, row: Int, col: Int): Unit =
    component.render(a, sel, foc)
}

trait TableRendererComp[A] extends Component {
  def render(a: A, sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean): Unit
}
```

Using like (at least the "configure" is gone...)

```
val tcr = new TableRenderer[MyObj](new MyRenderer)

class MyRenderer extends Label with TableRendererComp[MyObj] {
  def render(o: MyObj, sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean) {
     text = o.toString //or whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: I read your comment but at first didn't get it.  Only after I created several sub classes of `Table.AbstractRenderer` did I realize why I needed your code.  The improvement I would add is that you may as well pass the remaining `configure()` parameters to `render(a, sel, foc, row, col)`.  I eventually needed all of them