# How to put Buttons into Swing Table in Scala?

Tags: swing, button, renderer

For Java the solution is here:
[How to add button in a row of JTable in Swing java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475543/how-to-add-button-in-a-row-of-jtable-in-swing-java) (I need to put Buttons in given column, not a row).

When translating it into Scala I have the problem with setting new renderer for table column. There is no getter method for column and there is no getter method for column model. At least I don't see any: [Table API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/Table.html).

I need something like this:

```
table.getColumn(...
```

or

```
table.getColumnModel(...
```

to inject my ButtonRenderer.

**How to set a column with button with Swing table?**

### Update 1

Scala Swing Table has **peer** field which is Java JTable. I was able to set the renderer, but now there is another problem -- the renderer is not used.

**Renderer**

```
class ButtonRenderer extends javax.swing.JButton with  TableCellRenderer
{
  def getTableCellRendererComponent(table : javax.swing.JTable, 
                                   value : java.lang.Object,
                                   isSelected : Boolean, 
                                   hasFocus : Boolean, 
                                   row : Int, 
                                   column : Int) : java.awt.Component =
  {
    setText("it works");
    return this;
  }
}
```

**setting the renderer**

```
my_table.peer.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
```

### Update 2

It might be something wrong with Scala Swing, I rewrote the GUI part to Java Swing (in Scala) and buttons were inserted into table.

Comment: And these endless little frustrations in interoperabilty are the reason why I cannot use Scala for any large project. Maybe Kotlin will be different.

Comment: See this post. The one answer there looks promising.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195013/idiomatic-table-cell-renderers-in-scala