# Swing Log Appender

Tags: java, swing, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm trying to show log contents to the users of my Swing application on demand. Displaying a list of log events, possibly allowing them to see details about log messages, ideally something similar to what the eclipse "Error Log" view displays.

Are there any premade Log display components/log appenders for that?

I realize that I could easily append the String values to a Textarea but if possible I'd like more fancyness "for free" (searching, filtering by event, filtering by logger, export, etc.)

I'm currently using SLF4J with logback but I don't have any problems with switching to another logging framework if such a component exist for it.

Comment: *"..but if possible I'd like more fancyness "for free" (searching, filtering by event, filtering by logger, export, etc.)"*  Look to `JTable`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/), and either use it as a whole or reuse single components from it.

Comment: Check my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33657637/808901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at this.  While it's been an instructional exercise for me, and
quite close to being fully-usable, there's still a couple missing necessities.
Perhaps someone can help with the final touches.

## Background

This is part of a larger working application, so while I'm only
posting the code related to this question, there are some artifacts of
the application.  The code is in Scala, but downgrading to Java ought
to be straightforward.  I'm not including most of the `import` directives;
hopefully it's clear what classes I'm referring to.  I
believe the only two classes with conflicting simple class names are
[scala.swing.Component](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.swing.Component)
and [java.awt.Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Component.html).

## Overview

The code exists in the following files:

- `Main.scala` has the the code that creates the log window.
- `LogFrame` is the swing window that displays the log entries
- `LogModel` stores the logging data
- `AbstractBaseTableModel` is the superclass of `LogModel` as well as
  another class in my application not shown here.
- `TableAppender.scala` is what connects Swing to Logback.
- A one-line method that formats timestamps is in my package object because it
  is used elsewhere in my application.
- `logback.xml` has one line activating my new appender

## The Code

In `Main.scala` the Frame that displays the log output is made
visible:

```
object Main extends swing.SwingApplication {
  override def startup(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFrame = LogFrame
    if (logFrame.size == new Dimension(0,0)) logFrame.pack()
    logFrame.visible = true
  }
}
```

The `LogFrame` singleton object is defined in `LogFrame.scala`:

```
object LogFrame extends Frame {
  title = "Log"
  iconImage = new ImageIcon("log.png").getImage
  preferredSize = new Dimension(1200,370)

  object LogTable extends Table {
    model = LogModel
    Map(0 -> 50, 1 -> 32, 4 -> 400) foreach { m =>
      peer.getColumnModel getColumn m._1 setPreferredWidth m._2
    }

    override def rendererComponent(
      isSelected: Boolean, focused: Boolean, row: Int, column: Int
    ) = {
      val v = model.getValueAt(
        peer.convertRowIndexToModel(row), 
        peer.convertColumnIndexToModel(column)
      ).toString
      TableCellRenderer.componentFor(this, isSelected, focused, v, row, column)
    }

    import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.{ERROR,WARN}
    object TableCellRenderer extends AbstractRenderer[String, TextArea](new TextArea {
      lineWrap = true; wordWrap = true
    }) {
      val brown = new java.awt.Color(143,112,0)
      def configure(t: Table, sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, s: String, row: Int, col: Int) = {
        component.text = s
        model.getValueAt(
          LogTable.this.peer.convertRowIndexToModel(row),
          LogModel.columnNames.indexOf("Level")
        ) match {
          case ERROR => component.foreground = java.awt.Color.RED
          case WARN => component.foreground = brown
          case _ =>
        }
      }
    }
  }

  contents = new BoxPanel(Vertical) {
    contents += new ScrollPane { viewportView = LogTable }
  }

  def logEvent(event: ILoggingEvent) {
    event +=: LogModel
  }

}
```

The `LogModel` singleton is in `LogModel.scala`.

```
object LogModel extends AbstractBaseTableModel {

  final val columnNames = Array("Time","Level","Thread","Logger","Message")

  val data = ListBuffer[Array[AnyRef]]()

  def +=:(event: ILoggingEvent) {
    Array[AnyRef](
      formatTimeStamp(event.getTimeStamp),
      event.getLevel,
      event.getThreadName,
      event.getLoggerName.replaceFirst(".*\\.",""),
      event.getFormattedMessage
    ) +=: data
    fireTableChanged( new TableModelEvent(this) )
  }
}
```

These two lines in my package object define the
`formatTimeStamp()` method:

```
final val isoFormatter = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis
def formatTimeStamp(millis: Long)      = isoFormatter.print(millis)
```

The reason `LogModel` extends `AbstractBaseTableModel` is because my
application has some other table models that are updated all-at-once,
rather than one row at at time as the logging model is.  Thus
`AbstractBaseTableModel` has a `data` member of type `SeqLike`, and
the subclasses can use either an immutable `List` or a mutable
`ListBuffer` as desired.

```
import scala.collection.SeqLike

abstract class AbstractBaseTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  val columnNames: Array[String]

  val data: SeqLike[Array[AnyRef],_]

  def getRowCount: Int = data.size
  def getColumnCount: Int = columnNames.size
  override def getColumnName(column: Int) = columnNames(column)
  override def getValueAt(row: Int, column: Int): AnyRef = data(row)(column)
  override def isCellEditable(row: Int, col: Int) = false

  override def getColumnClass(columnIndex: Int): Class[_] =
    getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass

}
```

The `TableAppender.scala` file is small:

```
class TableAppender extends AppenderBase[ILoggingEvent] {
  def append(event: ILoggingEvent) {
    LogFrame.logEvent(event)
  }
}
```

Finally, the change to my `logback.xml` file is even smaller:

```
<appender name="swingTable" class="mypackage.TableAppender"/>
```

## Issues

The only remaining problems that are preventing me from deciding this
is better than an old-fashioned log-file are:

1) Because I've overridden `Table.rendererComponent()`,
`JTable.setDefaultRenderer()` does not work as usual.

2) I haven't figured out how to get the wrapped lines to be visible in
the Table.  All I know is that I have to increase the height of the
rows.

If those issues were resolved, the next thing would be to add
real-time filtering according to log level and logger names.  As it
is, I'm going to set this aside for now at least, but if anyone
has any suggestions, I'm interested in hearing them.

## References

The following resources were either useful to me in composing the foregoing
code, or might be useful in resolving the remaining issues:

- [Idiomatic use of Scala table cell renderers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195013/idiomatic-table-cell-renderers-in-scala#1347647),
  a very helpful SO answer by
  [oxbow_lakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16853/oxbow-lakes), but
  unfortunately does not address the `JTable.setDefaultRenderer()` issue.
- [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/),
  a blog post by [Rob Camick](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/),
  explains how to change the color of a table row.
- [How to wrap lines in a jtable cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965023/how-to-wrap-lines-in-a-jtable-cell),
  another SO question from
  [Arvodan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5751/arvodan).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net). It has a nice demo at this page. Try JXTable for example.