# scala.MatchError in Swing table rendererComponent

Tags: swing, scala

I face `scala.MatchError: 0 (of class java.lang.Integer)` when I try to add new row to table with custom rendered component:

```
import java.awt.Dimension

import scala.swing.BorderPanel
import scala.swing.Button
import scala.swing.Component
import scala.swing.Panel
import scala.swing.Table
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
import scala.swing.Label

object MatchErrorInTable {

  def initPanel() : Panel = {
    val tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(Array[Object]("col1", "col2"), 0)
    val panel = new BorderPanel
    class MyRenderer extends Label {
      def prepare(o: String) {
          text = "foo"
      }
    }
    val tcr = new Table.AbstractRenderer[String, MyRenderer](new MyRenderer) {
      def configure(t: Table, sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, o: String, row: Int, col: Int) = {
        component.prepare(o)
      }
    }
    val table = new Table(0, 2) {
      override protected def rendererComponent(sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, row: Int, col: Int): Component  = {
        col match {
          case 1 => tcr.componentFor(this, sel, foc, "bar", row, col)
        }
      }
    }
    table.model = tableModel
   val addButton = Button("add") {
      tableModel.addRow(Array[Object]("text", null))
   }

    panel.layout(table) = BorderPanel.Position.Center
    panel.layout(addButton) = BorderPanel.Position.South
    panel
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val mainFrame = new MainFrame()
    mainFrame.preferredSize = new Dimension(800, 600)
    mainFrame.contents = initPanel
    mainFrame.visible = true

  }
}
```

the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" scala.MatchError: 0 (of class java.lang.Integer)
    at com.mm.calendar.MatchErrorInTable$$anon$1.rendererComponent(MatchErrorInTable.scala:29)
    at scala.swing.Table$$anon$2$$anon$10.getTableCellRendererComponent(Table.scala:116)
    at scala.swing.Table$$anon$2$$anon$10.getTableCellRendererComponent(Table.scala:114)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
```

How it is possible that I got java.lang.Integer in rendererComponent?

I was mostly basing my solution on:
[Idiomatic table cell renderers in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195013/idiomatic-table-cell-renderers-in-scala)

I'm using 2.11.1 version.

Comment: Could it be that first column is 0 and not 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add another

```
      case _ => tcr.componentFor(this, sel, foc, "foo", row, col)
```

as a fallback in the match in `def rendererComponent`, it will at least work without an exception.

You have tow columns in your model, and the actual column indices will be zero and one; these get passed to `rendererComponent`.

---

To get a full demo:

```
import swing._
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

object MatchErrorInTable {

  def initPanel(): Panel = {
    val tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(Array[Object]("col1", "col2"), 0)
    val panel = new BorderPanel
    class MyRenderer extends Label {
      def prepare(o: String) {
        text = o // changed
      }
    }
    val tcr = new Table.AbstractRenderer[String, MyRenderer](new MyRenderer) {
      def configure(t: Table, sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, o: String, row: Int, col: Int) = {
        component.prepare(o)
      }
    }
    val table = new Table(0, 2) {
      override protected def rendererComponent(sel: Boolean, foc: Boolean, row: Int, col: Int): Component = {
        col match {
          case 0 => tcr.componentFor(this, sel, foc, tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString, row, col) // changed
          case 1 => tcr.componentFor(this, sel, foc, tableModel.getValueAt(row, 1).toString, row, col) // changed
        }
      }
    }
    table.model = tableModel
    val addButton = Button("add") {
      tableModel.addRow(Array[Object]("text 1", "text 2")) // changed
    }

    panel.layout(table) = BorderPanel.Position.Center
    panel.layout(addButton) = BorderPanel.Position.South
    panel
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val mainFrame = new Frame()
    mainFrame.preferredSize = new Dimension(800, 600)
    mainFrame.contents = initPanel()
    mainFrame.visible = true

  }
}
```

This way the values you add to the model show up in the table.
Of course in this snippet the two `case` statements do not make much sense; in this case the `match` is not required, as you always use the same renderer component.

Comment: thanks that solve the problem, but the exception seems pretty confusing to me

Comment: @MariuszMarciniak `javax.swing.JTable` is already a hell of a confusion. Add the half-baked Scala facade and your confusion is quadrupled :-O

Comment: @0__ couldn't agree more, but there are no good GUI frameworks for Scala and this is just supporting tool app

Comment: @0__ I agree as well. On top of that, there won't be scala-swing in 2.12, if they do not find a new maintainer. MariuszMarciniak: It *might* go away, that possibly matters to you.

Comment: @Beryllium I wouldn't worry about the future of Scala Swing. I use it _a lot_. As far as I know, there is already community back-up for continuing the development. Although the API is at times incomplete, Scala-Swing is a pretty finished project. Just some components like tree and table suffer from being weakly typed or convoluted.